# How to determine if elements of a column is in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named `df` , and I want to know the column `item` whether contains the element `a` and `c`.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'item':['a,b,c','c,d,e','a,b']})
```

`Input:`

```
df
    id   item
0   1  a,b,c
1   2  c,d,e
2   3    a,b
```

In the new column `contain_a` , `1` represents the column `item` contains the element `a` ,which is the same as the column `contain_c`.

`Expected:`

```
df
    id   item  contain_a contain_c
0   1  a,b,c          1       1
1   2  c,d,e          0       1
2   3    a,b          1       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df['contains_a'] = df.item.str.contains('a').astype(int)

df['contains_c'] = df.item.str.contains('c').astype(int)

>>> df
   id   item  contains_a  contains_c
0   1  a,b,c           1           1
1   2  c,d,e           0           1
2   3    a,b           1           0
```

Or, you could do it in a loop:

```
to_check = ['a','c']

for i in to_check:
    df[f'contains_{i}'] = df.item.str.contains(i).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 4):

For a generalized way of doing this, can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) specifying a separator

```
df.item.str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix('contains_')


    contains_a  contains_b  contains_c  contains_d  contains_e
0   1           1           1           0           0
1   0           0           1           1           1
2   1           1           0           0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `pandas.Series.str.findall`

```
df.join(
    df.item.str.findall('(a|c)')
           .str.join('|')
           .str.get_dummies().add_prefix('contains_')
)

   id   item  contains_a  contains_c
0   1  a,b,c           1           1
1   2  c,d,e           0           1
2   3    a,b           1           0
```